# Java/Androif Create an intent stating which Activity you would like to start

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to Create an intent stating which Activity I would like to start. I guess I'm correct because I keep getting `Cannot resolve constructor` on the `this, ActivityTwo.class` portion. The activity I want to launch is ActivityTwo.java

```
    Button launchActivityTwoButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bLaunchActivityTwo);
    launchActivityTwoButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO:
            // Launch Activity Two
            // Hint: use Context's startActivity() method

            // Create an intent stating which Activity you would like to
            // start

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityTwo.class);

            // Launch the Activity using the intent
             startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `this` with `WhateverYourActivityIs.this`, where `WhateverYourActivityIs` is the name of the activity class in which your code resides.

Or, if this code is in a fragment, replace `this` with `getActivity()`.